# jQuery - Função .prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, input

Eu tenho um `input` que vem desabilitado por padrão, porém eu queria habilitar o mesmo no carregamento da página por meio de jQuery, porém não está dando certo.

**Código do `input`:**

```
<input type="text" title="Número" name="billing[street][2]" id="billing:street2" class="input-text required-entry" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled="">
```

Eu tentei o código abaixo, porém não obtive sucesso:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#billing:street2').prop('disabled',false);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você precisa utilizar caracteres especiais no seu `seletor`, é necessário utilizar `\\`(duas barras invertidas), para que o caractere seja tratado como texto e não como uma expressão regular.
Outro erro contido no seu código é o caractere `j` após o `$`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billing\\:street2").prop('disabled',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" title="Número" name="billing[street][2]" id="billing:street2" class="input-text required-entry" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled="">
```

Aprenda mais sobre `seletores` [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção! Uma observação: o caractere `$j` não seria um erro, pois uso `$j.noConflict();` para que eu não tenha conflitos com outras bibliotecas. Mas enfim, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ah sim, compreendi...